# How to test own rails generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, generator

I have written my generator and want to test it.

What I tried:

- outdated gem, last update was in 2014 - https://github.com/stevehodgkiss/generator_spec
- write my own spec, but it seems generator is not run it test environment( [generator](https://gist.github.com/denysmedynskyi/53bd5e87c9345a592e7dcf0131991236), [spec](https://gist.github.com/denysmedynskyi/70b1aca515a6af81bebe54c479cea706) ) It fails with error `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - app/pages/denys.rb`

Comment: You should be unit testing these and if you're just using `thor` like rails is, then there isn't a ton to do.  Show us a snip of your generator and I can show you.

Comment: @Anthony snippet is here - https://gist.github.com/denysmedynskyi/53bd5e87c9345a592e7dcf0131991236